# Finding $\delta $ for $\lim_{x \to 0} x \ [3-\cos(x^2)] = 0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

When reading Spivak's calculus book, I stumbled upon this limit: $$ \lim_{x \to 0} x \ [3-\cos(x^2)] = 0 $$

Proof:

We have that $$0 < |x| < \delta $$ Also
$$ |x \ (3-\cos(x^2))| = |x| \ |3-\cos(x^2)| < \epsilon$$
Since,
$$ |3-\cos(x^2)| \le 4$$
we can write that:
$$ |x| \ |3-\cos(x^2)| < 4|x| < \epsilon$$
$$\therefore |x| < \epsilon \ / \ 4$$
$$\therefore \delta = \epsilon \ / \ 4$$

By letting $\delta = \epsilon \ / \ 4$, we get that $|x \ (3-\cos(x^2))|<\epsilon$ if $0 < |x| < \delta $.

Thus, $ \lim_{x \to 0} x \ [3-\cos(x^2)] = 0 $.

Since I don't have the book with answers, I can't verify my solution (the book is on its way).

Is there anything that I missed here? Maybe there is another way, more concise perhaps, of finding a $\delta $?

Comment: I think it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is absolutely correct.